# ScrollTop to element not work after multiple click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a navigation and want after click on each `li` `scrollTop` to top of element, but after click multiple times on `li` it not work right and I know why, for example scroll already is `0` then element top is `50`, scroll going to `50` then if you click another element with 150 offset top, scroll should going to 150 but it going to `200`, because it now on `50`. I tried two logic:

**A.** Make scroll to zero for each time user click, but it didn't work.

```
$('ul').stop().animate({
    scrollTop: 0 }, 0);
```

**B.** Subtraction element offset top - of - current scroll position but it didn't work too.

```
var aTop = parseInt($(this).offset().top);
var cTop = parseInt($('ul').scrollTop());
var offset = aTop - cTop;
```

Any idea?

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  var offset = $(this).offset().top;
  $('ul').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Sample 1</li>
  <li>Sample 2</li>
  <li>Sample 3</li>
  <li>Sample 4</li>
  <li>Sample 5</li>
  <li>Sample 6</li>
  <li>Sample 7</li>
  <li>Sample 8</li>
  <li>Sample 9</li>
  <li>Sample 10</li>
  <li>Sample 1</li>
  <li>Sample 2</li>
  <li>Sample 3</li>
  <li>Sample 4</li>
  <li>Sample 5</li>
  <li>Sample 6</li>
  <li>Sample 7</li>
  <li>Sample 8</li>
  <li>Sample 9</li>
  <li>Sample 10</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to *add* the `ul` element's scrolltop, not subtract it:

```
var offset = $(this).offset().top + $(this).parent().scrollTop();
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$('li').click(function() {
  var offset = $(this).offset().top + $(this).parent().scrollTop();

  $('ul').animate({
    scrollTop: offset
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
ul {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

li {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>Sample 1</li>
  <li>Sample 2</li>
  <li>Sample 3</li>
  <li>Sample 4</li>
  <li>Sample 5</li>
  <li>Sample 6</li>
  <li>Sample 7</li>
  <li>Sample 8</li>
  <li>Sample 9</li>
  <li>Sample 10</li>
  <li>Sample 1</li>
  <li>Sample 2</li>
  <li>Sample 3</li>
  <li>Sample 4</li>
  <li>Sample 5</li>
  <li>Sample 6</li>
  <li>Sample 7</li>
  <li>Sample 8</li>
  <li>Sample 9</li>
  <li>Sample 10</li>
</ul>
```